# Can't get JSON response with backbone and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, coffeescript

My apologies now, it's been a while since I last worked in Rails and this is my first taste of backbonejs. I'm using Rails and backbonejs (both latest - rails 4.1.1, backbone 1.1.2) on a project. The rails aspect is setup correctly and returning JSON as backbone likes it, like this:

`http://localhost:3000/artists`

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Jeff Beck",
    "sort_name":"Beck, Jeff",
    "musicbrainz_id":"14a4bc78-1c2d-4ca7-8d1b-9b58076a2a17"
  }
]
```

that's from a rails controller that looks like this:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :json => Artist.all
  end

[...]

end
```

the backbone model looks like this. It's in coffeescript.

```
class AppName.Collections.HomeCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: AppName.Models.Home
  url: -> '/artists'
  parse: (response) ->
    console.log "parse response %o", response
    response

class AppName.Models.Home extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'home'
  defaults: {
    name: 'default name',
    sort_name: 'default sort_name'
    musicbrainz_id: "default musicbrainz_id"
  }
```

the backbone router:

```
class AppName.Routers.HomeRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @homecollection = new AppName.Collections.ArtistsCollection
    @homecollection.reset

  routes:
    ""     : "index"
    ".*"   : "index"

  index: ->
    @homecollection.fetch 
      success: (collection, response, options) -> 
        console.log "success fetch collection %o, response %o, options %o",
          collection, response, options
        new AppName.Views.Home.IndexView collection: collection

      error: ->
        console.log "HomeRouter error fetch, response %o"
    undefined
```

UPDATE: the console.log output on the `fetch()` `success` callback looks something like this:

```
"success fetch
    collection"
            ArtistsCollection
                    _byId: Object
                    _events: Object
                    _listenId: "l3"
                    length: 1
                    models: Array[1]
                    __proto__: ctor
            ",
    response "
            ArtistsCollection
                _byId: Object
                _events: Object
                _listenId: "l3"
                length: 1
                models: Array[1]
                __proto__: ctor
            ",
    options "
            Object
                error: function (resp) {
                    parse: true
                }
                success: function (resp) {
                    __proto__: Object
                }
```

and then finally the view:

```
AppName.Views.Home ||= {}

class AppName.Views.Home.IndexView extends Backbone.View

  el: '#home'

  tagName: 'ul'

  template: JST["backbone/templates/home/index"]

  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @collection, 'sync', @render
    console.log "home index_view init, Home.IndexView.collection %o", @collection

  render: ->
    $(@el).html @template collection: @collection
    return this
```

Where I'm struggling is my fetch request in the backbone router returns a collection object, but from what I've read I should be getting the JSON? The console.log from the fetch request shows the same object for both the collection and response arguments passed to `success`

If I try interacting with backbone in the browser console I can do the following:

```
var home = new AppName.Collections.ArtistsCollection
var home = home.fetch()
JSON.stringify(home.responseJSON)
"[{"id":1,"name":"Jeff Beck","sort_name":"Beck, Jeff","musi... etc"}]"
```

So, after all that, where am I going wrong and why can I not get JSON data from the rails request and pass that to my backbone view template?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any help is welcome at this point. So, that the `success` callback returns the same object for the `collection` and `response` arguments is expected? As for the toJSON method on the collection prior to being passed into the template from the view, that method doesn't exist for me.

Comment: I tried formatting the output here, but it ended up as either a mess or unreadable, so here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/krHAGvmz) link for readability.